# Insert at Specific Array and Replace one existing Object in Array in ES6/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wanted to insert the `productColumn` 3rd to the last if `isEnabled` is true.
Also I wanted to replace `fish` column with `customerFish`.
How should I do that using modern Javascript like ES6 and above?

Codesandbox ------> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-wdj8mr?file=/src/App.js:0-1410)

```
  const updatedListData = isEnabled
    ? {
        ...listData,
        columns: [
          ...listData.columns.slice(0, -2), // All existing columns except the last two
          newProductColumn,
          ...listData.columns.slice(-2) // Add back the last two columns
        ]
      }
    : listData;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? (spread is ES6 already)

Comment: @pilchard. I think you missed the second problem, how do I replace the fish column?

Comment: I agree with pilchard. What *different* are you looking for? Also, can you [edit] to clarify what this fish column replacement is about? That seems like a one-off swap, so how exactly are you wanting to do that in a sane and maintainable way?

Comment: @DrewReese. Hi Drew, it just a column. nothing specific. It just needs to replaced by the `customerFish ` column

Comment: What exactly are you looking for overall? Like pilchard said, the Spread syntax is already es6. Are you wanting to learn how to insert/change elements of an array? If you [edit] the post to more clearly explain what an issue/problem is, and what you expect as a result, the post can go through the reopen review process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although mutating data is often seen as bad, in cases like this I think it's easier.

So below I clone the data, then just replace using old fashioned index specifiers, you could even then use `findIndex` etc to find the columns etc.

IOW: doing this I think is way simpler & powerful than trying to use spread syntax.

Below is an example.

```js
const listData = {
  columns: [
    {
      name: "created_at",
      isDefaultColumn: true,
      header: "Date created"
    },
    {
      name: "fish",
      isDefaultColumn: true,
      header: "Fish"
    },
    {
      name: "updated_at",
      isDefaultColumn: true,
      header: "Date updated"
    },
    {
      name: "bought_at",
      isDefaultColumn: true,
      header: "Bought at"
    },
    {
      name: "sell_at",
      isDefaultColumn: true,
      header: "Sell at"
    }
  ]
};

const newProductColumns = [
  {
    name: "newProduct",
    header: "New product?",
    isDefaultColumn: true
  },
  {
    name: "newProduct Two",
    header: "New product Two?",
    isDefaultColumn: false
  }
];

const customerFeeColumn = {
  name: "customerFish",
  header: "Customer Fish",
  isDefaultColumn: true
};

const isEnabled = true;

//lets clone root object, cause State change
const updatedListData = {...listData};

if (isEnabled) {
  //we are also going to mutate columns array let's copy
  updatedListData.columns = [...updatedListData.columns];
  updatedListData.columns[1] = customerFeeColumn;
  updatedListData.columns.splice(
      3, //start at index 3
      0, //dont delete any
      ...newProductColumns);  //now add the columns
}
  
console.log(updatedListData);
```

Comment: Sorry. I've edited my codesandbox link. `newProductColumn` is now an array

Comment: @Joseph  You mean if you wanted to add multiple columns, just use the good old `splice`   <-- ps.. Not `slice`  :)

Comment: Mind if you can fork my codesandbox?

Comment: @Joseph  I'll just update my snippet here, it's better than using codesandbox, as other users don't have to leave site, and you can run the snippet here too.

Comment: That’s ok. Pls also add another version that doesnt mutate the state. Thank you

Comment: @Joseph  This doesn't mutate the state,  :),, that was the point in using `structuredClone`,  ps.  This is safe to use with React, you won't get any strange things happening.. :)

Comment: What about the splice?

Comment: @Joseph  That's fine, we are splicing a copy, not splicing the current state.  Again this is not going to cause any issues.   Muting an array / object is not always bad, it's only bad with react if you mutate it's state eg. what you get back from `const [state, setState] = React.useState({})`...   IOW: Don't directly mutate `state`, but your fine to mutate a copy, and then `setState(someCopy)`..

Comment: @Joseph you're not using state. All you have is an array.

Comment: FWIW, most of the time you don't want to create a copy of the values in the array. In that case you could do `const updatedListData = [...listData]`.

Comment: I have applied it in my app and it says `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': (`

Comment: @FelixKling  Yes, I agree.   I did the structured clone version just to make it bullet proof, for those rare occasions you have some async code attached to an item, and debugging gets wonky.. :)

Comment: @Joseph   You mentioned modern JS, support table is here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone  if your trying to run this on an old browser I would pollyfill it..

Comment: @Keith. yeah I understand. I'm using modern browser though. It says something like `SamplePage.tsx:171 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': ({
      row: product,
      props
    }) => {
      return /* @__PURE__ */ _jsx(_Fragment, {
      ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.`

Comment: Or alternatively like @FelixKling say, in most cases you can just get away by cloning the `root` object,  Although it would be `const updatedListData = {...listData}` instead.

Comment: That removed the error. but the `newProductColumns` triples

Comment: @Joseph  Your previous error implies you was trying to clone some JSX, yes.  don't do that..

Comment: @Joseph  Sorry, yes. You will also need to clone the array if your not using `structuredClone`,, eg.    `updatedListData.columns = [...updatedListData.columns]`

Comment: Sorry but can't you edit your answer?

Comment: @Joseph  Yeah, give us a tick.

Comment: @Joseph  Updated, as you can see this is way easier than using spread, and were it gets really powerful, lets assume you wanted to replace the item with `name: "fish",` instead of using index, that would be trivial to do, but pretty much impossible with spread syntax..

Comment: Thanks. Let's say we have a condition whether to use the new array or the original one. How can we do that? For example: `const updatedListData = isConditionIsMet ? {...listData} : listData;`

Comment: @Joseph  Just use a good old `if` statement, updated snippet..